# How to Read an Image located in one of the Project Folder in JSP Web Application

Tags: java, image, jsp

My Project Directory is as below.

```
Web Application
|__Web Pages
| |  |__img
|  |    |__membershipcard.png
|   |__ImageCreator.jsp
|
|__Source Packages
   |__Functions
      |__CardCreator.java
```

I have a Java function which reads the Image located in the img folder the Java class is as follows.

```
public class CardCreator {

public static String MembershipCard() throws IOException {
    String ImgUrl = "";
    Image image = null;
    // Read from an input stream
    InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("web/img/membershipcard.png"));
    image = ImageIO.read(is);
    Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
    Graphics i = image.getGraphics();
    g.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN, 15));
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawString("123456789", 334, 63);
    g.drawString("Roger", 196, 138);
    g.drawString("5", 299, 163);
    g.drawString("05", 63, 221);
    g.drawString("2015", 90, 221);
    i.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.BOLD, 15));
    i.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    i.drawString("9874564", 395, 196);
    g.dispose();
    ImageIO.write((RenderedImage) image, "png", new File("test2.png"));
    ImgUrl = "Hello";
    return ImgUrl;
}
```

}

I am calling this function from my ImageCreator.jsp page like this which returns me the URL of the Image that is created by the Java Function.

```
<%
        String ImgUrl = new CardCreator().MembershipCard();
    %>
```

I am not able to access the Image file located in the folder I Mentioned and How do I output the Result Image in a different folder where I want all the cards to be saved.

Kindly Help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `ServletContect's realPath`, by passing it as a Parameter to MembershipCard from your calling jsp

```
public class CardCreator {

public static String MembershipCard(String path) throws IOException {
    String ImgUrl = "";
    Image image = null;
    // Read from an input stream
    InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(path + "/img/membershipcard.png"));

    ...

    return ImgUrl;
}
```

And JSP

```
<%
    String ImgUrl = CardCreator.MembershipCard(pageContext.getServletContext().getRealPath("/"));
%>
```

Since you have now location of `Application Context` use it to save your file where you want it to be accessed by JSP as well.

A Better approach would be having a separate class for maintaining such common variables throughout the application instead of passing it as parameter to methods.

Comment: Thank you very much Raja. It was a great Help. Worked 100%.